# How to Test Standard HTML Forms

Tags: testing, forms

What tools are best for lightweight testing of HTML forms? My particular use is **very light:** no multithreading issues nor elaborate test scripts: just fill in a form with particular values and let **me** click submit.

A Firefox plugin would be fine...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you looked at [Selenium IDE](http://seleniumhq.org/) or does this not fit the light weightness?

It is a Firefox plugin and although it does use scripts, it can record and playback with little effort.

Comment: Not sure, but I´ll give it a look.  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah I think it may be a good fit, it can be light weight if you use it simply through firefox, yet can be expanded later to be as hard core as you want. Good luck

Answer (score 2):

Try [Autofill Forms for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4775). Customizable and promises to fill every form with one click :-).

Comment: I th ink Autofill forms only works for standard forms with standard fields. I'm trying to test stuff that's in development.

Answer (score -1):

you can try Selenium IDE
................

Follow the white rabbit : http://seleniumhq.org/

Comment: Thanks but I'm pretty sure we have that answer already. You can vote it up, though...