# Click a checkbox which submits the form on phpunit

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, twig

I have a from where the user can de-subscribe to the newsletter. It's a simple checkbox which submits the form on click:

```
     <form action="{{ path('fos_user_newsletter') }}"  method="POST" class="fos_user_newsletter" name="fos_user_newsletter">

    <input type="checkbox" name="newsletterSub" value="newsletter" {% if user.newsletterEnabled == 1 %}
    checked
{% endif %} onclick="this.form.submit();"> Subscribe to Newsletter
```

I now want to click on the checkbox with PHPUnit to test it, i tried differend things, but it didn't work. How can I do it? I tried as link or submitting the form but as there is no button it doesn't work.

```
        // Check if Newsletter form exists!
    $this->assertTrue($crawler->filter('html:contains("Subscribe to Newsletter")')->count() > 0);
    //var_dump($client->getResponse()->getContent());
    $form = $crawler->form();
    $form['newsletterSub']->tick();
```

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13074889/symfony-2-phpunit-how-to-untick-checkbox-in-form-field It may provide the answers you seek.

Comment: it doesn't work for me, I get an other error called: "LogicException: Unable to submit on a "html" tag." I added my test code above.

Comment: I am not sure how you can use phpunit to test html forms as there is no easy way to specify keyboard input that i am aware of. This answer may be useful: [414680/how-to-test-standard-html-forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/414680/how-to-test-standard-html-forms)